# How to redirect ServerAlias - requests to ServerName and obey the subdirectories in the requests?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I want redirect all traffic to `example.com/*` to be redirected to `www.example.com/*`

I found [How can I redirect any ServerAlias to the respective ServerName?](https://serverfault.com/questions/301544/how-can-i-redirect-any-serveralias-to-the-respective-servername) which handles the topic in question and did what was recommended in the answer with four upvotes:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  !^www.example.com [nocase]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$        http://www.example.com$1 [last,redirect=301]
```

However, this redirect traffic going to `http://example.com/subdirectory` to `http://www.example.com` and **not** to `http://www.example.com/subdirectory` as desired.

Any medication on this issue?

Comment: Your rewrite is ok. Works as intended (tested :). It must be something else with your configuration.

Comment: Nope, it's not okay :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to create a new vhost and redirect in that:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  Redirect / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/something
</VirtualHost>
```